# Overlaying normal distribution curves

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data I have represents a bunch of normal distributions (~18000) belonging to two different classes (0, 1).

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbqGJ.png)

I've wrangled the data here:

```
url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00372/HTRU2.zip"
download.file(url, "HTRU2.zip") 
unzip("HTRU2.zip")
col_names <- c('Mean_IP', 'Stdev_IP', 'Kurtosis_IP', 'Skewness_IP', 
               'Mean_DM', "Stdev_DM", 'Kurtosis_DM', "Skewness_DM", "Class")
pulsar_data <- read_csv('HTRU_2.csv', col_names)
pulsar_data_summary <- group_by(pulsar_data, Class) |>
    summarize(mean_ip = mean(Mean_IP), mean_stdev_ip = mean(Stdev_IP), 
              mean_dm = mean(Mean_DM), mean_stdev_dm = mean(Stdev_DM),
             max_ip = max(Mean_IP), min_ip = min(Mean_IP)) |>
    mutate (as.factor(Class))
```

I assume there must be a way to use ggplot to overlay these distributions with the given information (just mean and standard deviation would be fine if there's no way to add kurtosis and skew) but can't figure out how.

Ideally I'd like it to look something like this crude drawing (with a low alpha so the overlaid lines can show the density of distributions):

What I want it to look like

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the ggplot2 question. I assume your data looks like this:

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(g = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
                 m = rnorm(4, mean = c(1, 1, 2, 2), sd = 0.1),
                 s = rnorm(4, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.1))
#  g         m         s
#1 0 1.1370958 0.5404268
#2 0 0.9435302 0.4893875
#3 1 2.0363128 0.6511522
#4 1 2.0632863 0.4905341
```

Then you can use `stat_function` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  lapply(split(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF))), 
         \(x) stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
                            args = list(mean = x$m, sd = x$s), 
                            aes(color = factor(x$g)))) +
  xlim(-1, 4)
```

[image: resulting plot showing four density functions two different colors]

Note that the y axis does not show probability (as your mock-up wrongly shows). If you want to have probability as y, you need to plot the cumulative distribution function (the integral of the probability density function).